# Creating a webpage and asyncronously loading app data off of it

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, memory-management, swift3

*I am using Xcode with Swift.*

### My Question

Is it possible to create your own webpage (preferably a free one, like wordpress) to load images/content off of? How would I do this? Would this fix my app's current memory(RAM) issues?

### **My Issue (more detail)**

I have created an app that loads hundreds of pictures for the user to view. Each picture is an object of a class that contains important information about the image. Thus I have all of the images in the "assets" folder and am associating them with the appropriate class object using "named" instead of "contentsOfFile." However because there are so many images being loaded, after scrolling through a couple hundred of them the app crashes due to full memory. Apparently (from what I've read) the images are cached, and the only way for them to either not be cached or to clear the cache is if you are loading them through a URL.

### **My Hope**

Ideally I would like to be able to update the webpage in order to automatically update the contents within my app (adding/changing images and their related data). Each object contains images and data for the image, and it is important to me that this data remain connected to the images. At the very least I'd like to be able to pull the images off of the webpage directly using my app's code to prevent crashing.

If it is possible to do this without re-writing the hundreds of lines of code that I used to create each individual object, that would be ideal. Is it maybe possible for me to put the code that creates each class object on the webpage and have my app read it from the page and create the objects? Would that even solve my problem?

If anyone could provide me with a detailed guide on how to do something like this or direct me to a pre-existing one, I would be extremely grateful, because I currently cannot find one.

EDIT: Some code was requested, and I could not format it properly in the comments.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        cell.imageView.image = cardsToDisplay[indexPath.item].image
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: As far as your memory problem is concerned. I would look into declaring your image objects with `weak` references.

Comment: @Danoram i believe they are default weak if you do not say otherwise, but correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Danoram just tried changing them all to weak, this instead made the app crash upon reaching the appropriate screen

Comment: interesting. We must go deeper! In the meantime yeah lets not do weak vars lol

Comment: @Danoram at this point I'm hoping to get anything that will solve any of the problems I've listed. Though I don't know how to get more people to see this question

Comment: Try updating your tags and question title to better reflect the curent issue. Which appears to be finding a way to maintain strong reference cycles to your images and dispose of them in `didReceiveMemoryWarning()`

Comment: I have an idea, which involves creating an array of pointers to each of your instantiated images (images will be declared as `weak`) in order to maintain a strong reference to each image. Then in `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` you set each of those pointers in the array or a portion of them to `nil` at which point those images will be disposed of. There was a question with the answer posted really recently in the last two days. Try have a look for that

Comment: [Found it!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227977/cache-that-can-purge-unused-objects-by-demand)

Comment: @Danoram I've been looking at that post, and i like the idea of creating a cache of al of my objects that gets purged. However Im not sure how to create a cache of my objects, and I can't comment on that post due to a lack of reputation

Comment: Just an update, I'm still working on solutions - in case you are still working on one. I've been having some problems myself trying to re-create a image-purging application.. `didReceiveMemoryWarning` never gets called in mine and my app just runs until it crashes too. I'm currently trying to learn as much as I can about memory management in swift. This may take a while

Comment: @Danoram I am still working on it as well, and will let you know if I find anything. Thanks for taking this journey with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you wanted was something like google firebase database, from which you can then download all the newest data every time the user opens the app in a wifi area. Using Firebase storage also seems to keep the RAM down. Look into firebase and similar services.

Answer (score 1):

Use `contentsOfFile` - the images won't be cached.

As to loading them from the web - it won't solve your problem because it will result in a bad (even worst) user experience. The images will load slowly (in comparison to load them from the disk). You can solve this by caching them as local files, but then again you should use `contentsOfFile` in order not to cache them in the memory. So loading the images form the web is useless.

Comment: I had tried using contentsOfFile before, probably shoulda mentioned that. It still had the same problem, I'd watch the memory fill up while I scrolled through pictures and it would crash. It also added the bonus of not running if I had an image missing, which was not fun to work with.

Comment: @TrevorJordy are you presenting the images in a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`?

Comment: I am using UICollectionView

Comment: @TrevorJordy are you reusing the cells?

Comment: I'll post some code tomorrow when I wake up, sorry to make you wait, and thanks for your time. I'll keep you informed

Comment: Here is a little code `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        
        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        cell.imageView.image = cardsToDisplay[indexPath.item].image
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }`